# How to split a list from the console by lowercase,uppercase and mix-case strings in python 3

Tags: python

This is my code, but it doesn't work. It should read text from the console, split it into words and distribute them into 3 lists and use separators between them.

```
words = list(map(str, input().split(" ")))    

lowercase_words = []
uppercase_words = []
mixedcase_words = []

def split_symbols(list):
    from operator import methodcaller
    list = words
    map(methodcaller(str,"split"," ",",",":",";",".","!","( )","","'","\\","/","[ ]","space"))
    return list

for word in words:
    if words[word] == word.lower():
        words[word] = lowercase_words
    elif words[word] == word.upper():
        words[word] = uppercase_words
    else:
        words[word] = mixedcase_words
print(f"Lower case: {split_symbols(lowercase_words)}")
print(f"Upper case: {split_symbols(uppercase_words)}")
print(f"Mixed case: {split_symbols(mixedcase_words)}")
```

Comment: by this `words[word] = lowercase_words` you mean `lowercase_words.append(word)`? Also the `split_symbols` function looks terrible. What does it even do here? Also I think you don't understand assigning. To put five into a variable called "something" you should do `something = 5`. Definitely not `5 = something`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues in your code.

1) `words` is a list and `word` is string. And you are trying to access the list with the index as string which will throw an error. You must use integer for indexing a list. In this case, you don't even need indexes.

2) To check lower or upper case you can just do, `word == word.lower()` or `word == word.upper()`. Or another approach would be to use `islower()` or `isupper()` function which return a boolean.

3) You are trying to assign an empty list to that element of list. What you want is to append the word to that particular list. You want something like `lowercase_words.append(word)`. Same for uppercase and mixedcase

So, to fix this two issues you can write the code like this -

```
for word in words:
    if word == word.lower():         # same as word.islower()
        lowercase_words.append(word)
    elif word == word.upper():       # same as word.isupper()
        uppercase_words.append(word)
    else:
        mixedcase_words.append(word)
```

My advice would be to refrain from naming variable things like `list`. Also, in `split_words()` you are assigning `list` to `words`. I think you meant it other way around.

Now I am not sure about the "**use separators between them**" part of the question. But the line `map(methodcaller(str,"split"," ",",",":",";",".","!","( )","","'","\\","/","[ ]","space"))` is definitely wrong. `map()` takes a function and an iterable. In your code the iterable part is absent and I think this where the input param `list` fits in. So, it may be something like -

```
map(methodcaller("split"," "), list)
```

But then again I am not sure what are you trying to achieve with that many seperator